# Round to down - Remainder emulation?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I need to Round (to down; so to floor) a [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), such as:

```
base = floor(index)
```

But I don't have that native/primitive function in the application I'm using.
So the best way would be:

```
base = index-index % 1;
```

which give to me the same result (if I'm not wrong). Unfortunatly, I'm forced to use only three math operations for `double`: Add, Multiply and Subtract. I don't have %.

How can I do it?

Comment: You could do $x-i$ for integers $i=1,2,\cdots$ and see when $x-i<0$, in case $x$ is positive (otherwise do something similiar, and check at the start whether or not $x$ is positive). If you have access to `round`, just rounding to the nearest integer, then you could do `round(x-1/2)`

Comment: I could use round(x-1/2). But for int (i.e. tie breaking 0.5) it round ho even (which I don't want; it is not flooring). What do you mean with `x-i for integers 1..2`? I don't get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an integer type available, and can assign a floating-point number to it, somehow rounding off the fractional part (up, down, nearest, doesn't matter as long as the result is either the integer above or below the floating-point number), and if you can compare integers and floating-point numbers, then for integer `n` do this:

```
n = index
if (n > index) then n = n - 1
```

If you have a `round` function,
you can also do the same thing with `round(index)`: subtract $1$ if the result is greater than `index`.

If you had neither such an integer type nor any rounding function, you could take the number $1.0$ (if `index` is positive) or $-1.0$ (if `index` is negative) and double it until it is larger in magnitude than `index` is. Let $\pm2.0^n$ be the resulting number after the last doubling. Then perform binary search for `index` between $0.0$ and $\pm2.0^n$ until the upper and lower bounds of the search are one unit apart. They will then be the floor and ceiling of `index`. This is somewhat more efficient than simply counting $1.0, 2.0, 3.0, \ldots$ until you find an integer larger than `index`.

To even more quickly get a power of $2$ larger in magnitude than `index`,
start with $2.0$ ($-2.0$ if `index` is negative), and repeatedly square
the number (changing sign after each squaring, if `index` is negative)
until you find the desired power of $2$.